# Input value is rendered twice as one element when pushed into an array

Tags: reactjs

When I type a word into the input and press the `Append` button, the word is then pushed into an array.

However, the word is rendering twice as one element in the array. "Foo" would be pushed into the array as ["Foo Foo"]

When `Undo` button is pressed, the element is popped. ["Foo Foo"] becomes [].

https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-cartwright-d14u6?file=/src/App.js

Please point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mutating the `textArr` when you do `textArr.push(action.text)`. You should do

```js
const TextEditorReducer = (textArr, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "append":
      // textArr.push(action.text);
      return [...textArr, action.text];
    case "undo":
      // textArr.pop();
      return textArr.slice(0, -1);
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
};
```

Because your `textArr` is not a primitive data type, the changes you'll make to it inside `TextEditorReducer` will affect its value outside of that function.

Comment: The reducer is called twice. Do you know why?

Comment: _There is no "problem". React intentionally calls your reducer twice to make any unexpected side effects more apparent. Since your reducer is pure, calling it twice doesn't affect the logic of your application. So you shouldn't worry about this._ - [gaeron](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/16295#issuecomment-610098654)

Comment: I can't really explain why, because I myself haven't used `useReducer` yet :D

Answer (score 1):

State in React is meant to be immutable. This means the old value must stay unchanged at all times. In your case you are chaning the old value then returning a new one. That's a common source of errors. Try something like this instead:

```
const TextEditorReducer = (textArr, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "append":
      //textArr.push(action.text);
      return [...textArr, action.text];
    case "undo":
      //textArr.pop();
      return textArr.slice(0, -1);
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
};
```

Comment: I appreciate the info!